# Anylogic, how can I create a dynamic batch size that depends on the number of arriving agents every day?

Tags: anylogic

Multiple agents X that are determined by a distribution arrive at source with a defined interarrival time. I need X to be also my batchSize, this means that every time there is a new arrival, the batchSize needs to change and adjust to X number of agents in that arrival.

I've tried using source.count() On Exit and then batch.set_batchSize(), but since source.count() won't set to 0 before a new arrival, it doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thank VERY much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable called `batchSize` of type `int`. In the source's `On before arrival:` field, type the following:

```
batchSize = uniform_disc(1, 10);
```

Of course, instead of the distribution I used, use whichever you need.

Then, in the source properties again, for the `Agents per arrival:` field, write `batchSize`.

In the batch block's `On enter:` field, write:

```
batchBlock.set_batchSize(batchSize);
```

Replace batchBlock with whatever your block is named.

That should do it.

Comment: This works assuming the batch block is directly after your source. If there are delays/services/etc. in between, you will need another approach.

Comment: This was absolutely helpful! Thank you Emile, I'm new to Anylogic.